# XSD error: a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '0.00' in attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xerces

I am parsing following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 
  <xs:simpleType name="Money">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{2}" /> 
      <xs:minInclusive value="0.00" /> 
      <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999.99" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

 
  <xs:element name="Document" id="Document">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Issue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="ChargeMinimum" use="optional" type="Money" default="0.00" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm getting an error:

> `a-props-correct.2: Invalid value constraint value '0.00' in attribute 'ChargeMinimum'. cvc-pattern-valid: Value '0.0' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '\\d+.\\d{2}' for type 'Money'.`

Comment: Do you get that error when just parsing/validating the schema? Or with a certain instance XML (containing e.g. `<Issue ChargeMinimum="0.0"/>`, perhaps)?

Comment: Interesting, this seems to be a (Java?) Xerces error which seems to check the representation of the ("normalized"?) minimum value `0.0` against the pattern. Seems like a quirk or bug in Xerces, I don't get any error of that sort with Saxon EE or .NET's built-in validator. Might be worth asking on the xml-developers mailing list or just to wait until the experts on schemas or some schema validator implementors show up here.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to happen here is that Xerces applies rule 2 from https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-attribute which says:

> 2 if there is a {value constraint}, the canonical lexical
> representation of its value must be ·valid· with respect to the {type
> definition} as defined in String Valid (§3.14.4).

So value constraint is the `default="0.00"`, the canonical lexical representation of the decimal `0.00` is (as far as I understand it) `0.0` and that value is failing validation against the pattern `<xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{2}" />`.

So based on my current reading of the spec Xerces is giving an appropriate error message.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce using Xerces-J, and I concur with [@MartinHonnen's assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75790045/290085) (+1).

As a work-around, consider using `xs:fractionDigits` instead of `xs:pattern` to limit the decimal places:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
  <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
  <xs:minInclusive value="0.00" /> 
  <xs:maxInclusive value="9999999.99" />
</xs:restriction>
```

---

Thanks to @MartinHonnen for pointing out a flaw in my previously suggested work-around.

Comment: @MartinHonnen:  You're right.  I had confirmed the original issue but not my workaround.  It's not the `xs:minInclusive="0.00"` value that's the problem -- it's the `default="0.00"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: `xs:fractionDigits` would be a much better work-around.